# VBA code to extract the Connections between containers from Visio into an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, extract, visio, connector

I looking to get some VBA code to extract the Connections between containers from Visio into a excel sheet.  In the excel spread sheet I'm looking to have Predecessors and Successors. Predecessor the beginning of the connector without the arrowhead and the successor with the arrowhead. The Predecessor to be the text that exists in the shape same with the successor.

i used a lot of Chat GPT code would not write anything to the file

Sub ExportAllShapeDataToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object
Dim xlWorksheet As Object
Dim i As Integer

```
' Create a new Excel application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Add a new workbook
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

' Set the worksheet
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' Initialize row number
i = 1

' Loop through all shapes in the active Visio page
For Each sh In ActivePage.Shapes
    ' Get the shape text
    Dim shapeText As String
    If Not sh.TextFrame Is Nothing Then
        shapeText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Else
        shapeText = ""
    End If
    
    ' Write the shape text to Excel
    xlWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Shape"
    xlWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = shapeText
    i = i + 1
    
    ' Loop through user-defined cells (data fields) of the shape
    For Each cell In sh.CellsU
        xlWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = cell.Name
        xlWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = cell.ResultStr("")
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
Next sh

' Save the Excel file
xlWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Jerod.cramb\Documents\VisioTestFile2.xlsx"

' Clean up
xlWorkbook.Close
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

I think it is the
Dim shapeText As String
If Not sh.TextFrame Is Nothing Then
shapeText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

Im not sure how to get the connector data.

Comment: Wow! Really ChatGPT can't do it? May be you must change prompt?

Comment: Thank you for update! In this code I can't find Visio-related variables. In this case you have embedded Visio object into Excel's sheet? What you mean as containers?

Comment: The containers are the shapes(boxes) that the connectors (arrows) link to.

Comment: More than decade ago I shared [my macro](https://surrogate-tm.github.io/surrogate/docs/T5_auto.vsd) in 3rd party [forum's thread](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4615.msg18087#msg18087).